# Drupal 6 Views 2 using Node Path as an argument

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Please consider helping a Drupal noob who is in danger of tearing out what hair I have remaining.

I have a view that I want to add an argument to so that it only displays the details of the specified product. Since I'm using URL aliasing the argument is in the form of shop/product1, shop/product2 etc. However, when I go to add an argument node path (which is what I have set to shop/product1 etc is not listed) the only I could use is Node: Nid but that doesn't work because my argument is not a node id but a path alias.

The workaround I've been using is to create a CCK field to store my node path and then create an argument using the CCK field. Is this the only option?

Regards,

Sean

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a custom module and define your own callback which would then work out the NID from the path and pass that as an argument to the view using [views_embed_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/views_embed_view/6).

There are some contrib modules which allow you to filter by PHP code which would probably do as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can still use NID as the argument, as that is what's in the actual path even though you are displaying an alias in the address bar.